# Passing an array to activity (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, converters

In the activity A, I have built an array q1 of Question and I passed to activity B:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), B.class);
i.putExtra("questions", q1);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

In the activity B:

```
Object c= getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("questions");
```

Now, how can I reconvert "c" in an array of Questions? I can not make a cast (Question[])

Comment: Is Question marked as `Serializable`?

Comment: Yes the Question marked as Serializable.

Comment: Then you should be able to cast it. Are you getting an Exception? If so, can you post the stack trace/logcat entries.

Comment: `Question[]` is *not* a generic array. If you really mean `Question[]`, then please change the title.

Comment: This code: `codeQuestion[] q= (Question[]) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("questions");` Generates: 07-31 12:25:00.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25735): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.studentteech/com.example.studentteech.Domanda}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to com.example.studentteech.Question[]

Answer (score 2):

this will be helpful.

```
 Question[] questions = (Question)context.getIntent().getExtras().get(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your objects need to implement the `Parcelable` interface.

In your Question class must implement `parcelable` interface. See the following code,

```
Question[] questions = //assign value;
Parcelable[] output = new Parcelable[questions.length];
for (int i=questions.length-1; i>=0; --i) {
    output[i] = questions[i];
}

Intent i = new Intent(...);
i.putExtra("QuestionArray", output);
```

//retreiving it from intent

```
Question[] questions = (Question[])intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("QuestionArray");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first activity you can send the array inside a bundle and then in the next activity that was created with the intent you can extract the array list from the bundle.

```
        Bundle b=new Bundle();
        b.putStringArrayList("option", optionMod);
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ad45.hw.hwapp.confirmation.class);
        i.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(i);
```

Then when you want to read the content in your new activity, create a new array List to store the one that was sent with the intent and extract the array from the bundle:

```
    public void getInfo(){
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
       options = extras.getStringArrayList("option"); 
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Question object must implement the Parcelable interface. You can put only primitive objects or objects that implement Parcelable.